# FTDI Chip ID on Mac OS Yosemite

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, ftdi

I'm trying to get run Sample App from

http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/FTDIChip-ID.htm

for Mac OS.

My problem is to get it compiled for Mac OS Yosemite.

I get this errors after "making" it :

```
ld: warning: ignoring file ./libftchipid.dylib, missing required architecture x86_64 in file ./libftchipid.dylib (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_FTID_Constructor", referenced from:
      _main in ChipID-3efebc.o
  "_FTID_Destructor", referenced from:
      _main in ChipID-3efebc.o
  "_FTID_GetChipIDFromHandle", referenced from:
      _main in ChipID-3efebc.o
  "_FTID_GetDeviceChipID", referenced from:
      _main in ChipID-3efebc.o
  "_FTID_GetDeviceDescription", referenced from:
      _main in ChipID-3efebc.o
  "_FTID_GetDeviceSerialNumber", referenced from:
      _main in ChipID-3efebc.o
  "_FTID_GetDllVersion", referenced from:
      _main in ChipID-3efebc.o
  "_FTID_GetErrorCodeString", referenced from:
      _main in ChipID-3efebc.o
  "_FTID_GetNumDevices", referenced from:
      _main in ChipID-3efebc.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

can someone help?

Comment: Are you sure that your ./libftchipid.dylib file is the x86_64 version?

Comment: It's created in 2006, so I do not think it is. But FTDI does not provide any other library for OSX for getting USB ID.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the way how to read the ID without this library. it is written in EEPROM.

`FT_ReadEE (ftHandle, 0x43, &wTemp)
(FT_ReadEE (ftHandle, 0x44, &wTemp)`

Comment: Same issue for a different platform (Raspberry), I'd like just to add that while the ID is stored in the words 0x43 and 0x44 to have a correspondence with what is visible in the FTDI tools some (non trivial) bit manipulation are required: see https://vyvoj.hw.cz/navrh-obvodu/je-skutecne-ftdichip-id-v-ft232r-unikatni.html (is not in english, but the source code is very clear)